# use nlog to write to rest service

Tags: json, rest, nlog

been at this for some time now,
i have a rest service that takes some parameter that i send via the query string. other then that i need to send via the request body some fields.
the format needs to be **json**.
here is a successful request made from postman for example:

```js
{
  "TransactionLogId": "6e6279a3-22d9-458d-b1c9-9b03a81556be",
  "CreatedDate": "2015-08-17T15:05:50.0143866Z",
  "LogType": "Info",
  "TransactionCode": "2831b7bc-9fc8-424d-857a-182397a5eb11",
  "ServiceName": "ESBService.WCF",
  "ServiceId": "8664e362-f63d-4d10-8a23-3b86b9f22cc7",
  "Servers": "******************",
  "Context": "EmployersSite",
  "RequestIPs": "**************",
  "UserId": "258a8c83-3f18-40d6-aea7-986dc0d97656",
  "ActivityTime": "2015-08-17T15:05:50.0143866Z",
  "LogSubType": "Info.RequestBegin",
  "Title": "RequestBegin",
  "Details": "",
  "RequestData": "{\r\n  \"Filters\": {\r\n    \"Mode\": \"Automatic\",\r\n    \"Type\": \"Applicant\"\r\n  }\r\n}",
  "EntityClass": "SavedSearch",
  "EntityId": "",
  "Methods": "SavedSearch_Search; SetSession",
  "SourceFilePath": "*******************\\PortalService.svc.cs",
  "SourceLineNum": 1025,
  "RunTime": 0.015
}
```

here is my config. lets say that all i want right now is just to send the exception message in details field.

here is my config:

```html
  <nlog throwExceptions="true" internalLogFile="c:\\Data\\Logs\\IES\\nlog_debug.txt" internalLogLevel="Warn">
    <variable name="LogBaseFolder" value="c:\\Data\\Logs\\tester" />
    <targets>
      <target type='WebService'
               name='ws'
               url='somesvc.vc/TransactionLog/Create?Context=Portal&amp;UserToken=a441b37f-3403-43fd-8f58-d1da3024133a'
               protocol='HttpPost'
               encoding='UTF-8'>
        <parameter name='details' type='System.String'  layout="  ${message}"/>
      </target>
    </targets>
 <rules>
      <logger name="*" writeTo="ws" />
    </rules>
  </nlog>
```

and my code:

```html
Log.Site.Error("erorrrr")
```

but the request never makes it it get error that the body is not right:

> message=Unexpected character encountered while parsing value: M. Path
>   '', line 0, position 0.

this is killing me could realy use some help. thanks

Answer (score 0):

don't worry it's actually something newbies encounters a lot  and there is a simple solution for that! – so REST your mind :)
So basically, when you pass the JSON back in the respond you need to Super-Serialize the object prior the response.Write(), do 
response.super(Object name_Object)
What it does it handles "deeper" encapsulation processes ('DIYA Encapsulation') which includes nested objects (methods and members)
But without the core functions (constructor, destructor..)

Hope it helps, and good luck.

BTW, Recommend you to read more about classes, nest objects, what is a constructor etc. 
It will help you further more as you develop as a developer! Cheers :)

Comment: sorry, but nothing you said had anything to so with what i asked. (btw i never herd of (reponse.super...),
anyways, this this is that the json i posted is a GOOD request made from postman (https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/postman/fhbjgbiflinjbdggehcddcbncdddomop) 
all i want to do is send the same type of request vua nlog to a rest service. i am able to create anything i want in files etc. the problem is when it gets sent to a rest service as json. Cheers :)